# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje de error debajo de cada formulario erróneo con PHP?

Tags: php

He buscado y observado diferentes ejemplos de formularios de contacto y temas sobre mostrar mensaje de error mediante **Array** sin éxito alguno.

Ahora mi pregunta es?

Existe una forma de incluir otra variable en `$errors` o un `array` para distribuir los mensajes de error en cada campo específico para mostrar los mensaje de error debajo o a los lados de cada campo del formulario erróneo.

**Mi formulario:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$errors = '';
$nombre = '';
$email = '';
$seleccionado = '';
$telefono = '';
$mensaje = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $errors .= "Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha";
  }
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nombre = test($_POST["name"]);
    $email    = test($_POST["mail"]);
    $telefono = test($_POST["phone"]);
    $mensaje  = test($_POST["message"]);
    $seleccionado = test($_POST['producto']);
  }

  if(empty($nombre)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su nombre."; 
  }else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombre)) {
      $errors .= "\n Sólo se permiten letras y espacios en blanco.";
    }
  }
  if(empty($email)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su email. "; 
  }else{
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .="\n email no valido";
    }
  }
  if(empty($telefono)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su número telefono. "; 
  }else{
    if(!preg_match("/^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/", $telefono)) {
      $errors .="\n Número no valido";
    }
  }
  if($_POST['producto'] == 0){
     $errors .= "\n Debe seleccionar un producto";
  }
  if(empty($mensaje)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su mensaje. "; 
  }
  if(empty($errors)) {
    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $msg= "Gracias por sus comentarios";
  }
}
?>
<?php
  function test($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
?>

<div class="error">
<?php 

if(isset($msg)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".$msg."</p>";
}else{
  if (isset($errors))
    echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
    # code...
?>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
      <?php
         $datos = array("Asunto","TV","Internet");
         for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
            if($i==$seleccionado) {
               echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }else {
               echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }
         }
      ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿has considerado hacer esas validaciones del lado del usuario y no desde el servidor? con jquery o js podrias hacerlo. al final cuando quieras comprobar todos los datos podrias hacerlo con esta librería de php [gump](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP)

Comment: me parece muy correcto validar del lado del cliente, para evitar peticiones al servidor, pero aunque se valide en jquery por ejemplo, tambien debe validarse desde el servidor, para evitar que un usuario con pequeños conocimientos pueda acceder al codigo y modificarlo @ReneLimon

Comment: @sioesi si. Por eso mencioné que al final, cuando envíe toda la información al servidor ocupe la libreria que recomendé

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que las validaciones las hagas con JS/JQuery, así te evitas que la aplicación llegue al servidor con errores del formulario y regrese otra ves al usuario, mejor que se valdie directamente del lado del cliente y luego se proceda a guardar la data correcta. Te recomiendo un plugin muy bueno llamado JQuery Validator (https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo probado en `localhost`.

Para empezar, e modificado las sentencias `if` `else` `if` por `if`, `elseif` `else`, pienso que se ve más limpio y mejor estructurado.

Para lanzar el mensaje de todo correcto, simplemente comprobamos que todas las `variables` del formulario están creadas correctamente. En caso contrario va lanzar según caso los mensajes de error para cada `input` mal rellenado o vacíos.

Es un sistema simple, siempre se podría avanzar mediante `jQuery`, `AJAX`, `PHP`,
o incluso se podría crear rápido una pequeña animación `CSS3` si uno tiene poco conocimiento, y muestra dichos mensajes de error durante un tiempo específico.

También e optimizado un poco el código `PHP`.

> Ejemplo **PHP**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>

<style>

.estiloError {
  color: red;
  animation: estiloError 7s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation: estiloError 7s linear forwards;      
}

@keyframes estiloError {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  2% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

  @-webkit-keyframes estiloError {

  0% { opacity: 0; }
  2% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }

}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<?php
//Activamos sesión.
session_start();

//Reseteo de variables.
$nombreValido = $emailValido = $telefonoValido = $errorsCaptcha = $errorsNombre = $errorsEmail = $errorsTel = $errorsMen = $errorsAsun = $nombre = $email = $seleccionado = $telefono = $mensaje = $captcha = NULL;    

//Definido formulario
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {    

  //Obtenemos datos para comprobaciones (preg_match y email filter) (Importante).
  $nombreValido = dataForm($_POST['name']);
  $emailValido = dataForm($_POST['mail']);
  $telefonoValido = dataForm($_POST['phone']);

  //Regla nombre
  if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errorsNombre = "\n Por favor ingrese su nombre."; 
  } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombreValido)) {
    $errorsNombre = "\n Sólo se permiten letras y espacios en blanco."; 
  } else {  //Caso verdadero obtenemos datos.  
    $nombre = dataForm($_POST['name']);
  }

  //Regla email
  if (empty($_POST['mail'])) {
    $errorsEmail = "\n Por favor ingrese su email. "; 
  } elseif (!filter_var($emailValido, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errorsEmail = "\n email no valido";
  } else { //Caso verdadero obtenemos datos.  
    $email = dataForm($_POST['mail']);
  }

  //Regla telefono.
  if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $errorsTel = "\n Por favor ingresar su número telefono. "; 
  } elseif (!preg_match("/^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/", $telefonoValido)) {
    $errorsTel = "\n Número no valido";
  } else { //Caso verdadero obtenemos datos.  
    $telefono = dataForm($_POST['phone']);
  }

  //Regla mensaje
  if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $errorsMen = "\n Por favor ingrese su mensaje. "; 
  } else { //Caso verdadero obtenemos datos.  
    $mensaje = dataForm($_POST['message']);
  }

  //Regla selecciona.
  if (empty($_POST['producto'][0])) {
    $errorsAsun = "\n Debe seleccionar un producto";
  } else { //Caso verdadero obtenemos datos.  
    $seleccionado = dataForm($_POST['producto']);
  }

  //Regla captcha
  if (empty($_POST['vcode'])) {
    $errorsCaptcha = "\n Por favor ingrese el código captcha";
  } elseif($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $errorsCaptcha = "Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha";
  }  else {
    $captcha = dataForm($_POST['vcode']);
  }

  //Comprobamos si todos los datos son verdadero.
  if ($nombre && $email && $telefono && $mensaje && $seleccionado && $captcha) {

    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$nombre." Email:".$email." Telefono ".$telefono." Informacion ".$mensaje;
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $msg = "Gracias por sus comentarios";    

  }      

}//End isset formulario.

//Function -> Salida de datos.
function dataForm($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<div class="error">

<?php 
//Caso enviar, mensaje OK, invisible formulario.   
if(isset($msg)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".$msg."</p>";
} else { //Caso falso mostramos formulario.
?>

</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">

    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
      //Mensaje error      
      <?php if (!empty($errorsNombre)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsNombre</span>";  }  ?>
    </div>

    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
      //Mensaje error     
      <?php if (!empty($errorsEmail)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsEmail</span>";  }  ?>
    </div>

    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
      //Mensaje error     
       <?php if (!empty($errorsTel)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsTel</span>";  }  ?>
    </div>

    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
       <?php
         $datos = array("Asunto","TV","Internet");
         for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
            if($i==$seleccionado) {
               echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }else {
               echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }
         }
      ?>
      </select>
      //Mensaje error     
      <?php if (!empty($errorsAsun)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsAsun</span>";  }  ?>
    </div>

   <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
       //Mensaje error     
       <?php if (!empty($errorsMen)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsMen</span>";  }  ?>


    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
      //Mensaje error     
      <?php if (!empty($errorsCaptcha)) {  echo "<span class=estiloError>$errorsCaptcha</span>";  }  ?>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php 
} //Fin else.
?>

</body>
</html>
```

> **Nota:** He modificado el ejemplo a tu comentario.

He añadido a la regla Captcha, el caso si está vacío, simplemente era añadir nuestra sentencias `if` `elseif` `else`. Podrías añadir los que deseas, si necesitas hacer más comprobaciones podría quedar algo como así  `if` `elseif`  `elseif` …. `else` (un ejemplo sería añadir otra comprobación de contar el mínimo o máximo de una cadena, etc.).

A los errores e añadido un `span` con el atributo `class` para así crear una regla estándar para dichos mensajes, en este caso una pequeña animación con un tiempo fácil de modificar (7 segundos), la animación tiene un pequeño efecto a su inicio y su fin.

Ejemplo **CSS**:

```
.estiloError {
   color: red;
   animation: estiloError 7s linear forwards;
     -webkit-animation: estiloError 7s linear forwards;      
}

@keyframes estiloError {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  2% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Ejemplo **HTML**:

```
<span class=estiloError>Tus mensajes de error</span>
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Hola @D.Bulten se ve mucho mejor la estructura del código y lo que es mejor funciona en localhost perfectamente sin ningún problema. Amigo sobre la animación para mostrar por un tiempo el mensaje de error suena muy interesante de seguro encontraré ejemplos en internet pero si no es mucho mi atrevimiento podrias añadir un ejemplo en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) una consulta como le añado un segundo mensaje de error al la validación del codigo captcha si lo deja en blanco mostrar un mensaje y si completa el campo pero con caracters erroneo mostrar el mensaje que los caracters no coinciden.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte lo estudiare detalladamente me servira de mucho estudiar los ejemplos y cada funcionamiento.

Comment: De nada @Josue, me alegro que te haya funciona tambien en localhost, esta tarde noche cuando regreso del trabajo modifico el ejemplo, con un segundo mensaje en el captcha.

Comment: @Josues ya he modificado mi respuesta, te e añadido el error si esta vacío el `Captcha` y también una pequeña animación `CSS3` para mostrar un tiempo determinado los mensajes de error, espero que te haya servido la respuesta, un saludo amig@.

Comment: claro que sí, gracias un abrazo saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es algo asi, obviamente esto esta sin `style` pero puedes imprimirlos dentro de un `<span>` o un `<p>` y darle clases para que vea bien abajo o al lado.

```
<?php
session_start();
$errors = '';
$nombre = '';
$email = '';
$seleccionado = '';
$telefono = '';
$mensaje = '';
$error_nombre =  "";
$error_email = "";
$error_telefono = "";
$error_seleccionado = "";
$error_mensaje = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
        //$errors .= "Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha";
      }
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $nombre = test($_POST["name"]);
        $email    = test($_POST["mail"]);
        $telefono = test($_POST["phone"]);
        $mensaje  = test($_POST["message"]);
        $seleccionado = test($_POST['producto']);
      }

      if(empty($nombre)) {

        $error_nombre = "Por favor ingrese su nombre.";
         $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su nombre."; 
      }else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombre)) {
            $error_nombre = "Sólo se permiten letras y espacios en blanco.";
          $errors .= "\n Sólo se permiten letras y espacios en blanco.";
        }
      }
      if(empty($email)) {
        $error_email = "Por favor ingrese su email.";
        $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su email. "; 
      }else{
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_email = "email no valido";
            $errors .="\n email no valido";
        }
      }
      if(empty($telefono)) {
        $error_telefono = "Por favor ingresar su número telefono. ";
        $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su número telefono. "; 
      }else{
        if(!preg_match("/^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/", $telefono)) {
          $errors .="\n Número no valido";
          $error_telefono = "Número no valido";
        }
      }
      if($_POST['producto'] == 0){
         $errors .= "\n Debe seleccionar un producto";
        $error_seleccionado = "Debe seleccionar un producto";
      }
      if(empty($mensaje)) {
        $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su mensaje. "; 
        $error_mensaje = "Por favor ingrese su mensaje. ";
      }
      if(empty($errors)) {
        $asunto = "";
        $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
        $destino = "contacto@example.com";
        $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
        mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        $msg= "Gracias por sus comentarios";
      }
    }
?>
<input type="text" name="nombre">
<?php  if(!empty($error_nombre)) echo $error_nombre;?>
<input type="text" name="email">
<?php  if(!empty($error_email)) echo $error_email;?>
<input type="text" name="telefono">
<?php  if(!empty($error_telefono)) echo $error_telefono;?>
```

Comment: @Josues ahi lo adapte, la verdad es que no se si se pueda hacer un array, ya que por ejemplo... si hubieran errores en todos los campos, sabriamos donde esta cada uno, pero si no, y falla por ejemplo el primero el de al medio y el ultimo, no tenemos manera de identificarlo.

Comment: Seria lo mismo o no? De todas formas tendria que buscar si en ese arreglo esta ese valor

Answer (score 0):

Depende como quieras la respuesta, si de forma inmediata mientras saltas de un textform a otro o despues de enviar con submit

En el primer caso te tienes que apoyar en Jscript, en el segundo con una variable global ($_session[]) que se vaya seteando de acuerdo al error

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Tanto las preguntas como las respuestas deben ser claras y concisas. En tu caso estás dando una vaga idea de cómo se podría solucionar el problema. Te recomiendo editar tu respuesta para ofrecer una solución que realmente solucione las dudas planteadas en la pregunta.